# data binding is not working on socket.io-client events

Tags: angular, sockets

I am using socket.io-client in my angular7 application for listening events from the node server. On the event, I want to show some data on-page. but data is not updating on the listening event. below is my code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as io from "socket.io-client";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-chat',
  templateUrl: './chat.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./chat.component.css']
})

export class ChatComponent implements OnInit {
  socket = io("http://localhost:3002");
  constructor() { }

  test:string;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.socket.on("adminrecivedMsg", function (data) {
      this.test= "hello";
    })
  }
}
```

chat.component.html

{{test}}

Comment: "this.test" will always be "hello" because you hardcoded it . try something like "this.test = data"

Comment: it has to be "hello". but the "test" expression is not updating in HTML. it always shows as empty in html.

Comment: okay, try logging something to the console and see if it emits something

Comment: I try that also. I am getting consoles when the event is emitted. but the "test" is not updating in HTML. but if I place the same "test" variable in any function it updating properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **arrow** function, this keyword reference of component is getting lost with the function keyword.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.socket.on("adminrecivedMsg", (data)=> {
      this.test= "hello";
    })
  }
```